# Visual Basic 6 and HMACSHA1 Google v3 Signature

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vb6, sha1, hmacsha1

I'm looking for a code to develop the algorithm HMAC-SHA1 on Visual Basic 6. I found a lot of code but for .NET, java, C# and more, but not for Visual Basic 6. I'm desesperate...

Can anyone help me? I need it for the new Google V3 identification.

And is not posible change the language :(

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?635398-VB6-HMAC-SHA-256-HMAC-SHA-1-Using-Crypto-API

Comment: http://vb.wikia.com/wiki/SHA-1.bas

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get the same results like those: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth#digital_signatures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [HMAC-SHA-256, HMAC-SHA-1 Using Crypto API](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?635398-VB6-HMAC-SHA-256-HMAC-SHA-1-Using-Crypto-API) yet?

Code there does both, wrapped in test projects that run the published validation vectors.

You might look at the new posts there which address your Google Maps API signature issue.

Comment: Thanks!! But the answer was published yesterday evening hehe :)

Comment: What answer was that?  Care to share so others can see?

Comment: The last answer on your link, someone has written on Sep 23th, here is the link with the code:

http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=105021&d=1379970454

Is a nice example for Google V3 signature :)

Comment: Great. I just misunderstood and thought you were saying you found yet another working solution somewhere else.